# Set up and solve an ordinary differential equation with initial value problem on rate of learning

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A language student has to learn 1000 words on a vocabulary list. The rate at which they learn the words is proportional to the number of words that the student does not know at any given time.

a) Set up and solve an ODE initial value problem for W(t), the number of words that the student has learned after t days.

b) Modify your Ordinary Differential Equation so that it applies in a situation where the student,while still learning words at the rate described above, also forgets a certain percentage of the known words each day.

Edit: I started by setting words unknown to be (1000-w); the rate of learning is: dw/dt=k(1000-w), where k is a constant (since rate of learning and words unknown are proportional).

I then do the integration, which makes it really messy... I got -ln(w-1000)+C1=kt+C2 (C1 & C2 are constants); I can then take e, where I *think* I'll get C3*abs(1/(w-1000))=C4e^kt, and I can simplify it. But I'm not even sure what I'm doing is right... This was our first homework due after 1 class, and seems a bit complicated, hence I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what aspect of this problem is giving you trouble?

Comment: I set dw/dt=k(1000-w), where k is a constant (since rate of learning and words unknown are proportional), and the integration gave me abs(w)=Ce^k(1000-w)*t, where C is another constant. I'm not sure how to proceed next - if assume initially student knows 0 word from the list, w(0)=0 doesn't really help to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You should edit that into the question. It will help you get answers faster. People around here like to see what work you've done on the problem already.